# How to add additional user data upon first social sign in with django-allauth?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

In Django REST framework, when a user signs in via a social account, say Google, I post to `127.0.0.1/accounts/google` with an 'access_token' from the frontend client. 'django-allauth' then pulls data like first name, last name, email from Google, and even creates a username. However, I want to enforce two additional required fields `dob` (date of birth) and `gender`, and allow for a custom username when the user first signs in via a social account. How can I POST to `127.0.0.1/accounts/google` with additional data? Or are there other ways to do so?

I tried changing `allauth.socialaccounts.form.SignUpForm`, but it doesn't seem to work with Django REST framework.